# Using mysql "IN" operator in this kind of query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the query below that uses union.

```
"SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT 1 AS `table`, 
            `comment_post_id` AS `feed_id`, 
            `blog_id` AS `from_blog`, 
            `comment_author` AS `author`, 
            `comment_content_stripped` AS `feed_title`, 
            `comment_content` AS `post_content_s`, 
            `type` AS `type`, 
            null AS `object_type`,
            `comment_date_gmt` AS `date` 
            FROM `wp_site_comments`
            UNION
            SELECT 2 AS `table`, 
            `post_id` AS `feed_id`, 
            null AS `from_blog`,  
            `blog_id` AS `author`, 
            `post_title` AS `feed_title`, 
            `post_content_stripped` AS `post_content_s`, 
            `post_type` AS `type`, 
            null AS `object_type`,
            `post_published_gmt` AS `date` 
            FROM `wp_site_posts`
        UNION
        SELECT 3 AS `table`, 
            `object_id` AS `feed_id`, 
            `blog_id` AS `from_blog`,  
            `user_id` AS `author`, 
            null AS `feed_title`, 
            null AS `post_content_s`, 
            `type` AS `type`, 
            `object_type` AS `object_type`,
            `date_added` AS `date` 
            FROM `wp_global_likes`
        UNION
        SELECT 4 AS `table`, 
            `object_id` AS `feed_id`, 
            null AS `from_blog`,  
            `user_id` AS `author`, 
            null AS `feed_title`, 
            null AS `post_content_s`, 
            `type` AS `type`, 
            `object_type` AS `object_type`,
            `date_added` AS `date` 
            FROM `wp_global_followers`
        ) AS tb
        ORDER BY `date` DESC"
```

Basically I wanted to select only the rows where `author` is in a comma separated values as follows:

eg. `$blog_ids = (23, 55, 19, 10)` and `$user_ids = (22, 55, 19, 40)`

The first table in union, the `author` is `comment_author` which is a user id.

The second table in union, the `author is`blog_id` which is a blog id.

The third and fourth table in union, the `author` is `user_id` which is a user_id.

Now, I wanted to somehow distinct the `author` as blog id and user id so my query will select rows where `author` is in `$blog_ids` and `$user_ids` uniquely.

I used,

`WHERE author in (" . $blog_ids . ")` and it returns correct. Now I wanted to include `$user_id`.

Please note that `$blog_ids` and `$user_ids` may have a same value.

I hope you get what I mean, this is i guess the best explanation I can make.

Comment: Your query is HIGHLY inefficient. Try using subqueries and joins to make it smoother.

Comment: @Yisera My problem is that, I wanted to sort them by date but the date columns for each table is different. Thats the primary reason why I use union.

Comment: create a sqlfiddle..Question will be more understandable...

Comment: There are various ways to sort them by date, set a date range if you must: `select ... from ... where date between 'yyyy-mm-dd and yyyy-mm-dd'`